# Desinenza dell'aggettivo riferito a più parole di genere e quantità diversi

Tags: adjectives, gender, suffix

Sono anni che mi imbatto in questo dubbio e ogni volta mi genera la stessa frustrazione.

Come si fa a trovare la desinenza giusta per un aggettivo che si riferisce a più parole che hanno ***genere e quantità diversi?*** Ecco! Ne ho appena fatto un esempio:

> genere e quantità *diversi*

Per quello che ne so si usa il plurale per rispecchiare il fatto che ci si sta riferendo a più cose, ma come si sceglie il genere maschile o femminile?

Nel caso sopra sembra che il maschile, a orecchio, suoni meglio.

Ma se dovessi scrivere qualcosa del tipo:

> un'auto dal look e dalle prestazioni aggressivi

suonerebbe peggio e sembrerebbe errato.

Usando il femminile invece suonerebbe un po' meglio, però poi se mi soffermo sulla frase ho comunque l'impressione che ci sia qualcosa che non va (il look non può essere *aggressiva*!).

Quale sarebbe in questo ultimo caso la forma corretta?

C'è una regola che definisce questo aspetto o si tratta di usare semplicemente la forma che suona "meno peggio"?

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma corretta è quella che suona peggio:

> Un'auto dal look e dalle prestazioni aggressivi

e la [grammatica italiana Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/concordanza_(La-grammatica-italiana)/) ne dà conferma:

> Quando, in una frase, un aggettivo qualifica due o più nomi di genere diverso […], si seguono due semplici regole.
>
> - Se i nomi sono tutti maschili o tutti femminili, l’aggettivo mantiene il loro genere e si declina al plurale, per evitare che la caratteristica espressa dall’aggettivo venga attribuita solo all’ultimo dei nomi
>     *Ho uno zaino e un portapenne rossi* (Ho uno zaino e un portapenne rosso farebbe pensare che solo il portapenne sia rosso)
> - Se i nomi sono di genere diverso, l’aggettivo si declina al maschile plurale
>     *Ho conosciuto un ragazzo e una ragazza spagnoli*

**N.B.** Attenzione al genere femminile di *auto* (su cui si potrebbe aprire un altro tema!).

Comment: Propongo ufficialmente di modificare questa regola :) Come si potrebbe cambiare per far si che questo tipo di espressioni suoni meglio?

Comment: Mettendo la parola di genere maschile alla fine, la frase dovrebbe suonare meglio: "Un'auto dalle prestazioni e dal look aggressivi".